# Get adhesive off if 12x12 peel & stick tiles? I used adhesive along with the peel & stick floor tiles. How do I get adhesive off the top of the tiles

Tags: adhesive

Need to get adhesive off of 12x12 peel & stick tiles? I used adhesive along with the peel & stick floor tiles. How do I get adhesive off the top of the tiles? I have adhesive all over my new peel & stick tiles. I don't want to ruin them.

Comment: How you do that?   What kind of adhesive?   What does the manufacturer label say about Clean up?   Some will clean up with water before dry but need mineral spirits after.

Comment: I have found that orange oil is a good solvent to soften mastic on the floor after s raping off vinyl floor ties.

Comment: Pics or it didn't happen.  For future reference, additional adhesive is usually a pain in the butt in all but commercial settings unless  you use a commercial type of tile that allows replacement of singles and has durability proportional to the strength of adhesive..